# Context of GcmIntentSerivce

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have app that uses Google Cloud Messaging to receive notifications. Each message begins with unique code and different action is taken depending on that code (display notification, start new service, etc).
One of the functions I would like to implement is to collect SIM card information. I have a SimCard class with getFullMsisdn method but I have a problem instantiating this class from within GcmIntentService and passing context to it.

Here is how I instantiate SimCard from onHandleIntent method of GcmIntentSerivce class:

```
SimCard simCard = new SimCard(this);
String simInfo = simCard.getFullMsisdn();
```

SimCard class:

```
public class SimCard {
   private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

    public simCard(Context context) {
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemSerivce(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    }

    public String getFullMsisdn() {
        return telephonyManager(getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
Cannot find symbol method getSystemService

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? All examples I find on the Web use TelephonyManager in Activity class which is not the case in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use Application Context.